# Linux 2.6 on imx: Can't log sent CAN frames using candump

Tags: linux, can-bus, socketcan, canutils

I have a custom build linux 2.6 running on a imx CPU. CAN communication with external nodes works like a charm, but the frames that I send to the nodes from my app is not printed when using "candump can0" in the terminal (when I run the same app on my host using a usb-CAN dongle this problem does not occur).

When extended CAN frames are sent they show up using candump.

I understand that it might be convenient that messages that is sent is filtered, but I should be possible to choose.

Any clues are welcome. I'm thinking that it might be some filtering in the driver that causes this.

The FLexCAN driver has the following config files:

> abort           br_propseg      dump_rx_mb      loopback        state 
>   wakeup          bcc             br_pseg1        dump_xmit_mb    maxmb 
>   std_msg         xmit_maxmb      bitrate         br_pseg2
>   ext_msg         modals        subsystem         boff_rec        br_rjw
>   fifo            power           tsyn            br_clksrc       driver
>   listen          smp             uevent          br_presdiv
>   dump_reg        local_priority  srx_dis         wak_src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have been at this issue many times but given up. But know I stumbled on the solution:

The setting file called srx_dis in the FlexCAN folder controls this behaviour. 
So, if you want to be able to read the CAN frames you send on the imx53_loco, do the following:

```
ifconfig can0 down
echo 0 > /sys/bus/platform/devices/FlexCAN.0/srx_dis
ifconfig can0 up
```

The reason I want to do this is for creating a service tool on the same device which can log all CAN frames.

Answer (score 1):

The can-utils package requires SocketCAN, which was integrated into the stock kernel 2.6.30.

If you are using SocketCAN, you should be able to turn on loopback to receive messages that are being transmitted from your interface (and they **must** actually be transmitted on the wires to be received via loopback).

From bash:

```
ifconfig can0 down
ip link set can0 type can loopback on
ifconfig can0 up
candump can0|grep C0FFEE
```

and in another terminal:

```
cansend can0 00C0FFEE#00112233445566
```

Comment: It is FlexCAN that is used. I tried your suggestion, but that command is not recognised so i did "echo 1 > /sys/bus/platform/devices/FlexCAN.0/loopback" instead. The result was that receiving msgs stopped working. One strange thing  I discovered: if I send a Remote Request frame like 123#R, that msgs is printed with candump.